# How to Implement Google Tag Manage in Salesforce Lightning Pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, google-analytics

We are trying to implement google tag manager in Salesforce Lightning pages but we are getting error while we are insert google tags in Lightning component. Please help how to fix the issue.[image]

Answer (score 2):

See [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm). Basically, what you need to do is to create a new Static Resource (Setup > Develop > Static Resource, or available in the Developer Console), then "include" the library into your component or app:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.googleAnalytics}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

Use afterScriptsLoaded to do things with GA after it is fully loaded, if necessary.

Note that not all libraries work with Lightning, so you will need to test GA first to see if it will work.